# Dialkylation reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

In the synthesis of ethyl 2-benzyl-2-methyl-3-oxobutanoate, is the nucleophilic substituion of a benzyl (chloride) group an Sn1 reaction?

The experiment is conducted in ethanol (protic) and is under reflux, but most textbooks have it as an Sn2?

Will it then be a mixture of the two?

Comment: Do you mean ethyl 2-benzyl-2-methyl-3-oxobutanoate? Do you mean addition of the benzyl group (not benzene group)?

Comment: Yes, sorry the nucleophilic substitution occurring in the presence of benzyl chloride.

Comment: what are you reacting with the benzyl chloride to give the desired product

Comment: benzyl chloride plus sodium ethoxide and ethyl 3-oxobutanoate

Answer (score 1):

Both mechanisms will probably be present but $S_N2$ will dominate because the enolate anion is a strong nucleophile. $E2$ will not occur because there are no $\beta$ hydrogens available on the benzyl chloride. Despite the relative stability of the benzyl cation, especially in protic solvents, the strong nature of the enolate nucleophile and the lack of an $E2$ pathway means that $S_N2$ will probably dominate.

For a comparison of alkyl halide reactivities with different nucleophiles, see [this link](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/VirtTxtJml/alhalrx3.htm#hal9).

Comment: if you were to perform a second alkylation, the yield would be quite low given the steric effects of having another benzyl group added. However, why is it necessary to have a stronger base for the second alkylation? The statement that alkyl group groups are electron-donating is so vague..

Comment: sorry i'm slightly confused. do you mean adding the methyl group as a second alkylation. if so how are you adding it?

Comment: Ok, so if I started with ethyl 2-benzyl-3-oxobutanoate. If I added methyl iodide for instance, would I need a stronger base than sodium ethoxide? It's really just a question of whether that benzyl group is electron-donating?

Comment: a strong base is used to generate significant quantities of the enolate. in this case the main factor is steric hindrance due and so using a small alkylating agent is a more important consideration. methyl iodide is probably the best option as you have suggested. i don't think there's any reason why you couldnt use sodium ethoxide apart from the possible side reaction of it substituting the methyl iodide to form methyl ethyl ether

Comment: Yes, that's a moot point (Sn1). If water was to be added to ethyl 2-benzyl-3-oxobutanoate, would it act in a Sn1 reaction with benzyl chloride -seems unlikely? Or would it act as a nucleophile, although this again seems unlikely?